# Flexbox grid in Android Browser

Tags: css, flexbox, android-browser

Some CSS;

```
  #category-grid {
    width: 100%;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
        -ms-flex-flow: row wrap;
            flex-flow: row wrap;
    margin-top: -10px; }

  .category-grid-link {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -webkit-flex: 0 0 33.33%;
        -ms-flex: 0 0 33.33%;
            flex: 0 0 33.33%; }

  .category-grid-link img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%; }
```

to make a 3 x 3 grid. Works a treat in everything except Android Browser. Where instead of a grid, I get the long line and no wrapping.

How do i get this to work?

jsfiddle here; https://jsfiddle.net/chrispink/3069vpdp/3/

Comment: Have you already checked [**google**](https://www.google.com/search?q=flexbox+android+browser&oq=flexbox+androed&aqs=chrome.4.69i57j0l5.5471j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)?

Comment: Yes, Michael_B and found many conflicting suggestions, none of which work elegantly or even at all. I believe it not to be possible.

Comment: Works fine on my Android 6. What version are you using, and do you have a screenshot?